# How do I display multiple charts in pandas python

Tags: python, ipython, pandas

Using Ipython notebook and the pandas module, I have a bit of code that iterates through a series and makes a number of bar charts (or is supposed to). It only produces the last chart that it should. The data is the funds raised by day and radio show, and I want a chart for each day. I suspect this may be a combo pandas/ipython problem, but I don't know how to approach it.

The code is this:

```
print pledge[pledge.Date==k[0]].groupby('Break')['Amount'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
kcount =0;••••••••••••••••••••
for k, v in grouped.Amount.iteritems():
    if k[0] <> kcount:
        kcount=k[0]
        print k[0];
        print pledge[pledge.Date==k[0]].groupby('Break')['Amount'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

and the output I get is

```
05/02/2012 

Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)

05/03/2012

Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775) 

05/04/2012 

Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)

05/05/2012 

Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775) 

05/06/2012

Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
```

[image: Bar chart]

With only a single chart at the end, of the last iteration.

Comment: To be clear, by print, I mean show up on the screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of those plots appears on the same subplot; pandas creates a figure in the first `plot` call but leaves it to you to create further figures and subplots after that. Try inserting `plt.figure()` (cf. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`) before each plot command.

Comment: Thanks Wes! Saw your talk at Pycon which introduced me to pandas, it's been neat.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `print` a plot object (or you can, but you only see the `Axes(...)` text).

IPython should make a `display()` function available that you can use on each plot to show it.